# Q: The proxy repo in Nexus cannot download the special SNAPSHOT structure from remote repo

Tags: maven, nexus

there is a special SNAPSHOT structure in the remote repository as following.
[image]

i create a proxy repository in Nexus pointed to this remote repository. but an error happened while running mvn packaging. the error message is as following:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dispatch-admin: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.yueyue:dispatch-admin:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.yueyue:order-search-interface:jar:1.2.1.SNAPSHOT in aliyun_release2 (http://192.168.200.224:8081/repository/aliyun_release2/)
```

and there is a warning while pulling the package as following
[image]

but it is OK while using remote repository for mvn packaging. and the message is shown as following while pulling the package.
[image]

what should i check first for this problem? many thanks in advance!

Comment: The picture contains only metadata but no jar file...

Comment: The structure of the repository seems to be incorrect. The versions looking like SNAPSHOTs are looking like release versions.

Comment: the maven-metadata.xml in 1.2.1.SNAPSHOT is pointing to 1.2.1.20200619-6. it seems that the 1.2.1.SNAPSHOT is checked first and then find the 1.2.1.200619-6 version in last picture. but it cannot be found while using Nexus proxy repo